# Magento 2: Change "Qty" label to "Select Qty" in product view page

Tags: module, price, magento2.2

***Is there another way to change the product page "Qty" label text to "Select Qty" than overriding the file***

```
/var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml
```

in custom module ?

Maybe a method similar to changing the content of blocks like this ?

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.sku">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Theme::lorem.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: you need to override the core file into your custom module...it's Magento Way. .. 2nd way is trying black CSS trick to manipulate the text and this should not use . So better to use Magento way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this file into app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml

And this file will be override to magento core file

Comment: This solution works fine, however, I was wondering if there was a nicer way to do it, like for blocks:<referenceBlock name="product.info.sku">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Theme::lorem.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>

Comment: what is exactly you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can override translate suggestion in your own theme:

> your_theme_root/i18n/en_US.csv

```
...
"Qty","Select Qty"
...
```

Dont't forget clear cache. I hope it will help.

Comment: The problem is that when I really want to use label "Qty" then it also gets replaced.

Comment: Be little clear what exactly you want

Comment: Ok, then sole solution is override template file as provided above. Another way isn't.